# Is it analytic ? $f(z)=z^2\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, cauchy-riemann-equations

Please find the question and its solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My answer gone wrong dont know why, I think the answer marked in the question is wrong.

**My try:**

I solved for CR equations and replaced x=y=0 and found CR equations satisfied. But not sure why in the solution it says CR equations doesn't satisfy.

Please let me know what should be the correct answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: since $u_x(0,0)=u_y(0,0)=v_x(0,0)=v_y(0,0)=0$, $(0,0)$ *is* a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations (and, since the partial derivatives are continuous at $(0,0)$,  $f$ differentiable at $0$).

Comment: you mean mine answer to tick "is analytic" is correct ?

Comment: No. The function $f$ is not analytic, since it is differentiable at $0$ and only at $0$.

Comment: so what should be the asnwer ??? i think correct answer is not mentioned in the options

Comment: I also see no correct option.

Comment: thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is poorly phrased. It awkwardly mixes real and complex differentiability as well as pointwise and local notions. Let me try to clear things up.

As a map $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ the map $f(z)=z^2\bar z$ has polynomials as component functions. In particular, it is *real differentiable* everywhere and even *real analytic* (meaning that all components have convergent real power series expansions near all points in the domain).

However, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are only satisfied at $z=0$. So as a map $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$,  $f$ is *complex differentiable* at $z=0$ but not at any $z\ne0$. This means that $f$ is not *complex analytic* at zero. Otherwise it would have a convergent complex power series expansion in a neighborhood of zero, and would thus be complex differentiable in that neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you for trying :)